# Remove all items of same name from list of sublists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, recursion

I'm trying to remove all instances of a certain string from a list which contains sublists. For example, something like this:

```
myarray = ['a', 'a', ['b', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'c', 'd', 'a'], 'a', ['a', 'd']]
```

ends up like this

```
mylist = [['b'],['c','d'],['d']]
```

after removing all the instances of `'a'`.

I have used this code:

```
def delnodata(lst, what):
for index, item in enumerate(lst):
    if type(item) == list:
        delnodata(item, what)
    else:
        if item == what:
            lst.remove(item)
delnodata(mylist, 'a')
```

but the output is:

```
[['b', 'a'], ['c', 'd'], 'a', ['a', 'd']]
```

I've seen a lot of similar questions on this site, but unfortunately my programming skills aren't good enough to put this together myself!

Comment: Don't modify the list during iteration.

Comment: `for index, item in enumerate(lst[:])`

Comment: you should pay attention to the answers that warn you about iterating over and mutating the same list. There is more info here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896752/removing-item-from-list-during-iteration-whats-wrong-with-this-idiom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd do this recursively. This will also work for an arbitrary nesting level.

```
myarray = ['a', 'a', ['b', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'c', 'd', 'a'], 'a', ['a', 'd']]

def nestremove(lst, what):
    new = []
    for item in lst:
        if isinstance(item,list):
            new.append(nestremove(item,what))
        elif item != what:
            new.append(item)
    return new

print(myarray)
myarray = nestremove(myarray, 'a')
print(myarray)
```

The function returns a new list, so we don't have to remove items from the original list while iterating over it, which as others have already pointed out can be dangerous (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022764/python-removing-list-element-while-iterating-over-list) question, especially the comments). Instead, you can just reassign `myarray`.

output:

```
['a', 'a', ['b', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'c', 'd', 'a'], 'a', ['a', 'd']]
[['b'], ['c', 'd'], ['d']]
```

Answer (score 3):

First use for `for index, item in enumerate(lst[:])` so it loops through the entire copy of `lst` second `delnodata(myarray, 'a')` not `delnodata(mylist, 'a')` as you have put it

```
myarray = ['a', 'a', ['b', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'c', 'd', 'a'], 'a', ['a', 'd']]
def delnodata(lst, what):
    for index, item in enumerate(lst[:]):
        if type(item) == list: # This if statement is optional
            delnodata(item, what)
        else:
            if item == what:
                lst.remove(item)
    print lst

delnodata(myarray, 'a')
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code returns a new list, with `'a'`s removed. It doesn't modify lists in place, which can cause mysterious problems.

### source

```
myarray = ['a', 'a', ['b', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'c', 'd', 'a'], 'a', ['a', 'd']]

def testme(data):
    for item in data:
        if type(item) is list:
            yield list( testme(item) )
        elif item != 'a':
            yield item

res = list( testme(myarray) )
print res
assert res==[['b'],['c','d'],['d']], res
```

### output

```
[['b'], ['c', 'd'], ['d']]
```

Answer (score 2):

removing one item at a time from a list is very inefficient, as the following items all need to be shifted to fill the space each time. You should just create a new filtered list instead

```
>>> def remover(data, r):
...     return [remover(x, r) if isinstance(x, list) else x for x in data if x != r]
... 
>>> myarray = ['a', 'a', ['b', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'c', 'd', 'a'], 'a', ['a', 'd']]
>>> remover(myarray, 'a')
[['b'], ['c', 'd'], ['d']]
```