# Delete N items at every Nth multiple in list?

Tags: python, algorithm, list, math

I've been writing some code that involves inserting random characters into a list, and then removing those characters. Imagine you have a string:

```
['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x']
```

With this as an input, you get this as an output:

```
['x', 'x', 'a', 'r', 'x', 'x', 't', 'q', 'x', 'x' 'j', 'z', 'x', 'x']
```

I have this code written. I tried this for *removing* those random characters:

```
iterations = 0
removal = 0
for s in my_list:
if iterations % 3 == 0:
    removal = 0
    for letters in range(2):
        del my_list[removal + iterations]
    removal += 1
iterations += 1
```

This just removes some of them, and I can't really figure out the pattern. The idea is that this would be able to take out, say, five characters every eight iterations through a list. Or any number of characters every any number iterations.

Comment: Mutating a `list` like that will lead to trouble, as the indices will move around after each mutation.

Comment: could you give an example of how the output should look like depending on the `characters` and `iterations` that you want to parameterize?

Comment: See: [Removing Item From List - during iteration - what's wrong with this idiom?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896752/removing-item-from-list-during-iteration-whats-wrong-with-this-idiom)

Comment: Check your whitespace.  I think you may have left out an indent when you copied from IDE to the stackoverflow input box.

Comment: Could be the case; I just typed it over because I'm switching between OS's to get to my IDE. It's a really pathetic solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you can insert character in order pattern, then you should have to ability to remove those characters in the same order.

Well, assume that insert the character 2 times and the position to insert is 3.
Then you need to remove the every 4th elements first

```
>>>for i in range(3, len(my_list), 3):
       my_list.pop(i) # I have a problem with my python, so I could only use pop() to remove
['x', 'x', 'a', 'x', 'x', 't', 'x', 'x' 'j', 'x', 'x']
```

Then you need to remove every 3rd elements

```
>>>for i in range(2, len(my_list), 2):
       my_list.pop(i)
['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x']
```

Comment: This seems like the simplest solution, but I don't understand it. I thought that range() only takes two parameters?

Comment: OK, it's the amount by which it increments. Kudos to you.

Comment: range(start, end, step)

Comment: Also, because it's incrementing by three, you have to have it stop before the end of the list.

Comment: But every time you insert the character, you have add 1 to start and step

Answer (score 0):

As one of the commenters noted, it is not going to be easy to randomly start removing items from a list based on indices. What I would do to solve this problem would be to store some random value in the indices you want to remove than filter the array into a new array by checking if for that value.

```
   iterations = 0
   removal = 0
   placeholder = "TO_DELETE"

   for s in my_list:
     if iterations % 3 == 0:
       removal = 0
     for letters in range(2):
       my_list[removal + iterations] = placeholder
     removal += 1
     iterations += 1

   my_list = [i for i in my_list if i != placeholder]
```

Comment: This is great. I considered doing this, however for the purposes of the application, I would prefer that these random characters are discreet (as in inconspicuous, not the opposite of continuous.) In reality, the list will contain many characters that aren't all 'x'.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're encountering in your code is that of modifying a list while iterating over it.

Here's an alternative approach using `cycle` from `itertools`:

```
from itertools import cycle

def stride(iterable, take, leave):
    pattern = cycle([True] * take + [False] * leave)

    for value, take in zip(iterable, pattern):
        if take:
            yield value
```

Such that if `x = ['x', 'x', 'a', 'r', 'x', 'x', 't', 'q', 'x', 'x', 'j', 'z', 'x', 'x']`, then:

```
>>> list(stride(x, 2, 2))
['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x']
```

If `take` or `leave` is large, then this wastes memory by making a `pattern` list of size `take + leave`. So instead we can make a generator helper function:

```
def take_or_leave(take, leave):
    while True:
        for _ in range(take):
            yield True
        for _ in range(leave):
            yield False

def stride(iterable, take, leave):
    pattern = take_or_leave(take, leave)
    for value, take in zip(iterable, pattern):
        if take:
            yield value
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm looking for a solution that doesn't have to worry about dependencies during packaging, so I'm trying to do things without modules.

Comment: @theDoctor5000 `itertools` is in the standard library. There is therefore no dependency issue -- anyone who has python has `itertools`. Furthermore, the second approach uses no imports whatsoever.

Comment: Ok. This might be what I ultimately implement. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

I like approaching these sorts of things with wonky one-liner functions. Here's what I have:

```
removeStuff = lambda myArray, delEvery: [myArray[x] for x in range(len(myArray)) if x%delEvery!=0]
```

Usage:

```
>>> removeStuff([1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 3)
[2, 3, 5, 6]
```