# Why my list removes only one of two or more same values?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I made this function which removes all the odd numbers from a list. (I can't modify the original list)

Code:-

```py
def purify(sequence):
   purified = sequence
   for i in purified:
       if i % 2 != 0:
          purified.remove(i)
   return purified
```

The function works on most of the list but if a list have same values like `[4, 5, 5, 4]` it returns `[4, 5, 4]`.
I have changed the code to achieve what I required but I am just curious why this happens?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing Item From List - during iteration - what's wrong with this idiom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896752/removing-item-from-list-during-iteration-whats-wrong-with-this-idiom)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`purified = sequence` doesn't create a copy of `sequence` and assign to `purified`, rather both variables point to the same object, which you are trying to do. In addition, you are also modifying the same list you are iterating on, hence the weird behavior.

You have a few choices, and all of them work on Python 2.7

- Make a copy of sequence via `sequence[:]` called list splicing, and iterate on it

```
def purify(sequence):

    #Iterate on copy of sequence
    for i in sequence[:]:
        if i % 2 != 0:
            sequence.remove(i)
    return sequence

print purify([4, 5, 5, 4])
#[4, 4]
```

- Use list-comprehension to only pick even values from the list

```
def purify(sequence):

    #Pick only even values
    return [item for item in sequence if item%2 == 0]

print purify([4, 5, 5, 4])
#[4, 4]
```

- Use `filter` to filter out odd values

```
def purify(sequence):
    # Iterate on copy of sequence
    return list(filter(lambda x:x%2==0, sequence))

print(purify([4, 5, 5, 4]))
# [4, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't try to remove elements while iterating. Also, `purified = sequence` doesn't actually create a copy of `sequence`. The best way to do this is to use a list comprehension like so:

```
def purify(sequence):
    purified = [i for i in sequence if i % 2 == 0]
    return purified
```

Answer (score 1):

(I could have sworn I answered a dupe of this, but I can't find it...)

Anyway, the reason is that you are modifying a sequence while iterating over it. You should do something like this instead:

```
# Python 3
def purify(sequence):
    purified = sequence.copy()
    for i in sequence:
        if i % 2 != 0:
            purified.remove(i)

    return purified

# Python 2
from copy import copy

def purify(sequence):
    purified = copy(sequence)
    for i in sequence:
        if i % 2 != 0:
            purified.remove(i)

    return purified
```

Alternatively, you could start with an empty `list` and add elements that satisfy your criteria:

```
def purify(sequence):
    purified = []
    for i in sequence:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            purified.append(i)

    return purified
```

Or, with a `list` comprehension, this:

```
purified = [i for i in sequence if i % 2 == 0]
```

Comment: I tried first method it threw the following error ```AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'copy'``` And sorry but why ```for``` is indented?

Comment: @Lucifer That's not right. Try restarting your shell. The indentation is a mistake, fixed.

Comment: I tried this ```print purify([4, 5, 5, 4]```, it gave that error. Can you explain why?

Comment: @Lucifer Works fine for me. I believe you're using Python 2. I will edit my answer (the other two methods should work).

Answer (score 1):

On python2.7 use the `copy` module.

**Ex:**

```
from copy import copy

def purify(sequence):
    purified = copy(sequence)
    for i in sequence:
        if i % 2 != 0:
            purified.remove(i)

    return purified
print purify([4, 5, 5, 4])
```

Answer (score 1):

by using *filter*

```
# python 2.x
your_list= filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, your_list)

# python 3.x
your_list = list(filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, your_list))

print(your_list)
```

explanation:

- lambda is a single line nameless function, returns if the number is even.
- filter is test for truthfulness of that on **your_list**

*cheers!*