# Is it safe to use xor for variable swapping in PHP

Tags: php, operators

Is it safe to use this kind of variable swapping in php ?

```
$a^=$b^=$a^=$b;
```

Comment: *(related)* [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998903/php-i-i-crashed-the-server

Comment: This sounds like a terrible idea. Imagine what this would do e.g. to objects or arrays

Comment: `$a = "cats"; $b = "fail whale";`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, because the variables may not be types that can be XORd the way you expect. The PHP idiom for swapping two variables (of any scalar type) in one line is:

```
list($a, $b) = array($b, $a);
```

Or simply:

```
[$a, $b] = [$b, $a];
```

Comment: Yes it does... I wasn't sure list() worked with arrays but I tried it and it does work.

Answer (score -2):

Only correct when both are integer.
It's readability is poor,and efficiency is not good too,why use it?